# Table builder pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, functional-programming

Trying to combine functional style (immutable objects) and flexibility of property setters. For the sake of example, let’s say we have a soil types table with two attributes: Color and Name. I am looking for a way to alternate Names, but not Color. Here is how I solved it:

```
        // retrieving: all objects are immutable
        SoilTypes types = SoilTypes.Default;
        ISoilType clay1 = types.Clay;
        ISoilType clay2 = types[3];

        // derive an alternated immutable copy
        SoilTypes altTypes = types
            .With(tt =>
            {
                // tt.SensitiveFines.Color is still read only
                tt.SensitiveFines.Name = "Very sensitive fines!";
                tt[2].Name = "Purely Organic soil!";
            });

        // retrieving: everything is immutable
        ISoilType sensitiveFines = altTypes.SensitiveFines;
```

Where this interface is immutable:

```
public interface ISoilType
{
    Color Color { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

And this class is mutable:

```
public class SoilType : ISoilType
{
    public static implicit operator SoilType((Color Color, string Name) tuple) =>
         new SoilType(tuple.Color, tuple.Name);

    internal SoilType(ISoilType source)
        : this(source.Color, source.Name)
    {
    }

    internal SoilType(Color color, string name)
    {
        Color = color;
        Name = name;
    }

    public Color Color { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this non-generic class is immutable:

```
public class SoilTypes : SoilTypes<ISoilType>
{
    public static SoilTypes Default = new SoilTypes(
        (White, "Undefined"),
        (Red, "Sensitive Fines"),
        (Green, "Organic Soil"),
        (Blue, "Clay"),
        (Orange, "Silty Clay"));

    public SoilTypes(params SoilType[] types)
        : base(types)
    {
    }

    public SoilTypes With(Action<SoilTypes<SoilType>> update)
    {
        var copy = this
            .Select(t => new SoilType(t))
            .ToArray();

        update(new SoilTypes<SoilType>(copy));
        return new SoilTypes(copy);
    }
}
```

while this generic base used in both situations:

```
public class SoilTypes<TType> : ReadOnlyCollection<TType>
    where TType : ISoilType
{
    internal SoilTypes(TType[] types)
        : base(types)
    {
    }

    public TType Undefined => this[0];
    public TType SensitiveFines => this[1];
    public TType OrganicSoil => this[2];
    public TType Clay => this[3];
    public TType SiltyClay => this[4];
}
```

Comment: `// tt.SensitiveFines.Color is still read only` -- could you elaborate what you mean/wht is Color "read only"? I don't see how the Color attribute is different from the Name in the code provided.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko `SoilType` class does not have a setter for `Color`.

Comment: Oh, right. Hard to notice a three-letter long missing keyword. :)

Comment: I'm trying very hard but I still have no clue what this is about ;-( what advantages this have over a builder pattern? Why do you want to change the `Name` in a semi-mutable-immutable fashion? Btw. the `SoilTypes` should be `SoilTypeCollection`. Collections do not have plural names ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t Compiler will not allow you to write `SoilTypes.Default.Clay.Name = "Dirty thing"` but do allow to write  `SoilTypes.Default.With(alt => alt.Clay.Name = "Dirty thing")` to derive and override `SoilTypes` content, so we combine immutability with the syntactical efficiency of property assignments. My API is way wider then 5x2 table, so I do need it. P.S. I feel guilty about `SoilTypes` name, but it is how domain experts reference it - it is not just a technical artifact (container) - it is actually a business object.

Comment: @t3chb0t This `SoilTypes` object is an input for some kind of analysis, I would like to allow access to it after calculation has been performed, but do not allow to change after the fact. The same time - there should be a way to tweak it originally here and there. There are actually around 15 rows (soil types) x 8 adjustable columns (attributes) in total.

Comment: [Do not declare interfaces for immutable objects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189473/38663)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not fully immutable becasue I am able to change the `Name` with a simple cast:

```
altTypes.Dump();
((SoilType)altTypes.SensitiveFines).Name = "foo";
altTypes.Dump();
```

The underlying data type is still `SoilType` so the interface does not protect the data from being overriden.

Consider a user that writes a function like this one because he doesn't like interfaces :-)

```
public static void foo(SoilType bar)
{
    bar.Name = "new name";
}
```

and calls it

```
foo((SoilType)altTypes.SensitiveFines);
altTypes.Dump();
```

`Name` changed. Unfortunatelly I have no idea how to prevent it yet.

Comment: I would say that it is the same trick like using `IReadOnlyList<T>` as a field type for a mutable collection. It is not bullet proof, but good enough to deliver the point of immutability. Good business logic code has no casting operators at all :)

Comment: @DmitryNogin true, that's why it's better to call `AsReadOnly` and not just rely on the interface. It's hard to prevent the data from people who doesn't know this _rule_ and try to hack into everything :-]

Comment: Frankly speaking, I just usually need a tip for myself to understand from the API shape what a hell it was about many years ago... :) Agree, you are right - some kind of mutable `AltSoilType` (inherited from `SoilType`) builds a more understandable dichotomy. Thanks!

Comment: C# scares me out on everyday basis - one can not extend a get-only property with a setter after inheriting. Common, it is a total shame.

Comment: @DmitryNogin This might have something to do with the fact that a getter-only property gets backing field that cannot be accessed from code, see [Is it possible to access backing fields behind auto-implemented properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8817161/235671)

Comment: I have tried a none auto-implemented properties as well.

Comment: I have defined `SoilType` this [way](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/161607/95635) now.

Answer (score 2):

Guess, I must start with a disclaimer again -- after multiple rereadings, still unsure what exactly the code tries to achieve.

**The big confusion (of mine)**

There's one thing I really don't like about `SoilTypes<TType>`, namely the ad hoc-ish mapping to collection entries *by index*.
The consumer of the class will have to know that implementation detail, right?

Don't have a C# compiler in front of me at the moment so I could play with things.

Is there a way to keep `public static SoilTypes Default = ...` and the `public TType Undefined => this[0];` as close together as possible (meaning, in the same class)?
Not sure if it is achievable.

**On naming the lambda parameters**

As a minor thing, I'd note that `tt` is a bit confusing. Bet, you know we can write `(@type => ...`.

**Readability**

I know that `.With(...)` fluent syntax is very well known, I haven't really seen that working with a collection (non-scalar) object, though.
In other words, while you're not inventing anything new with this idiom, it's still a bit unintuitive to me.
Please disregard this comment if you find it a subjective thing. :)

**P.S.** Good question, just like many others that you post on CR!

Comment: 1) Yep, you will need a VS2017 for this :) It is just to ensure that property assignments operations are syntactically correct in a special context only + implementing prototype inheritance between immutable objects, which are safe to share and reuse. 2) My business logic requires access to records by name and index. 3) Nope, there is no way to put population and shortcuts at the same class. 4) Lambda parameter represents temporary mutable container, so it could probably be `@types` or `alt`.

Comment: @DmitryNogin I wish my comment was more helpful

Answer (score 2):

I have defined mutable/immutable dichotomy in a cleaner way according @t3chb0t answer:

```
public class SoilType 
{
    internal SoilType(Color color, string name)
    {
        Color = color;
        Name = name;
    }

    public Color Color { get; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    internal AltSoilType Mutable =>
        new AltSoilType(this);
}
```

And

```
public class AltSoilType : SoilType
{
    internal AltSoilType(SoilType source)
        : base(source.Color, source.Name)  
    {
    }

    public new string Name 
    {
        get { return base.Name; }
        set { base.Name = value; }
    }

    internal SoilType Immutable => 
        new SoilType(Color, Name);
}
```

Comment: This should be bullet-proof and I share your C# feeling sometimes ;-P like here where it's possible to make the setter `protected` but not `virtual` (I tried this previously while experimenting with it)